# Career profile not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

My [career profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/careers.stackoverflow.com/ioannishristofakis) is not found, is there a reason for that? I have set my profile to public, since yesterday it used to work.

[image]

Comment: This link works for me: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ioannishristofakis The link you pasted into your question is this: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/careers.stackoverflow.com/ioannishristofakis - let us know where you saw that link because that sounds like something's messed up.

Comment: You are right, I add a new photo, I have circled the link.

Comment: Well that definitely *used* to work! I will take a look.

Comment: this is also true for my profile on careers.

Comment: OK I can see now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix has now been pushed for this (it wasn't me so I can't take credit really!)